# SDL2 in a VS2015/C++ panel

Tags: sdl2, visual-studio

I'm trying to use SDL2 in a panel (VS2015/C++) and cannot find solid examples of how to connect the two. Anyone know how this is done?

I've tried some code found in various places, but no luck yet.  The code below was my latest attempt. I'm using latest version of SDL2.

```
SDL_Window* sdlWnd = SDL_CreateWindowFrom((void*)mapPanel->Handle);
SDL_SetWindowTitle(sdlWnd, "SDL Window - Set by SDL");
SDL_Surface* s = SDL_GetWindowSurface(sdlWnd);
SDL_FillRect(s, &s->clip_rect, 0xffff00ff);
SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(sdlWnd);
SDL_ShowWindow(sdlWnd);
```

Comment: What is currently happening?

Comment: Well, nothing.  I have no indication of anything happening in the panel.  I should see a magenta SDL window...

Comment: Any `SDL_GetError()`s? Does the title not change either?

Comment: Wow...it would help if I actually called the function that I created to test the SDL window.  So, "operator error" strikes again..../facepalm

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it. And these things happen.

Comment: Ok, still no SDL2 window embedded in the panel.  I am getting token errors (error LNK2028: unresolved token) when I use the SetParent function.  I've tried many different options but cannot make the token errors go away.  Can anyone tell me know to fix the token errors?  Here's a link to my project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73008990/G2.zip

Comment: Sorry, but we really aren't here to fix your errors for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of `SDL_Window` as physical pixels, and `SDL_Renderer` and a place to store settings/context.

So you create a bunch of resources, and hang them off of the renderer; and then when its ready, you tell renderer to put it all together and send the results to the window.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  See my comment above; professional humor only...